# Why am I unable to change key bindings to arrow keys when playing Minecraft Pocket Edition on PC using an emulator (BlueStacks)?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, emulation, keyboard

I play Minecraft Pocket Edition on PC (using BlueStacks emulator) as I don't want to buy another copy of MC for Java. When I went to Settings and tried to change the keybindings of the move keys (WASD) to the arrow keys, it didn't work. So I am stuck using WASD to move. I find the arrow keys more convenient. How do I change the key bindings?

[image: Settings config stuck on WASD for left, right forward and backward]

Comment: Why are you using an emulator to play Bedrock on PC? It's on PC already...?

Comment: I bought MC on my phone. I didn't want to spend 25 bucks for it again on PC cuz apparently you can't transfer Minecraft to different devices even if you buy it on one account.

Comment: @BongoMan You should be able to transfer Bedrock Edition by logging in with your microsoft account. Java Edition Minecraft is separate, which you'd have to pay 20 dollars for.

Comment: @Corsaka I logged in successfully, and it shows that I have bought minecraft bedrok edition, but doesn't allow me to play.

Comment: @BongoMan You download the launcher from https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download **to your PC**, and sign in with the microsoft account, and it doesn't let you play?

Comment: @Corsaka That was a really heplful suggestion. I went to the site and downloaded the launcher, but it only allows me to play the trial version. To make MC realise that I have already bought the game, I need to buy the game AGAIN and log in my account.

Comment: Why didn't the rebinding work? What should happen is 1- you move your mouse above "walk forward 'w'" 2- you press left click 3-it says waiting for input or something similar 4- you press the ↑ key on your keyboard 5-you no longer see 'w'. So at which step did it not work?

Comment: At step 4, I tried pressing the up - arrow key in place of w for walk forward, but it didn't register. It was as though the arrow keys could not be accepted at all.